# UIView seems locked - this is a strange one

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7, initialization

Ok this is the strangest problem ever, well maybe not but anyway :-)

I have a project and everything seems to work fine, I have added CoreData and all the frameworks (including others) so in short the code is working without errors or glitches.

Except this one: My initial `UIViewController` does not allow me to change its color or add any subViews to it. In the code yes no problem. In storyboard again not a problem, but when I run it in the Simulator or the app it just **shows up white**.

Now i have no `code` or `storyboard` image, which I know is frowned upon, but I really could not tell you where my problem is.

**However this is what I have tried:**

1) Created a New `UIViewController` in Storyboard.

2) Created a New Objective-C Subclass file, with a different name and deleted the old one

3) Created a New Project and transferred everything across

4) Deleted and Reset the app on the iPhone Simulator

5) Deleted the app on the devices

Now when I add the code `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];` to any other `UIViewController` within the project or add an `UIImageView` anywhere else, it works. Just the **initial** `UIViewController`.

Can someone please be so kind to help out - I am out of ideas here and I do not want a white UIViewController as my landing page.

Again I apologise for no visual aid or code, but I would be posting my whole project.
Thank you in advance.

===================================

## **Edit**

```
for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
{
    [btn removeFromSuperview];

}
```

it takes away the UIImageView.

Comment: How do you get to the other view controllers that work? You get something that works on the initial screen?

Comment: Yeah - buttons in the UINavigationColler in which it is embedded work and for some reason coded buttons work as well. Sorry forgot about that.

Comment: Autolayout? Inadvertently hidden view? What debugging have you done of the views on display (`recursiveDescription` of the main view)?

Comment: It's not Autolayout and I haven't done debugging, because I don't know what it is I am looking for, but I will try what you just posted.

Comment: Ok I couldn't get an answer from the debugger and I will need more practise with that, however I got the change of color of the UIView working now. made a silly mistake there - But the UIImageViews are still not showing.

Comment: I don't need code for them, so there is no linking error there.

Comment: What silly mistake? Add a breakpoint to `viewDidAppear:`, then, in the debugger type `po [[self view] recursiveDescription]`.

Comment: The silly mistake was calling a method in the wrong place - something I over looked. going back to the debugger now.

Comment: It would be useful if you show some code related to this view, view controller setup and such. Me wild guessing isn't particularly efficient...

Comment: Ok, I have added some code, I will keep trying different things

Comment: Updated the code - this causes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
{
    [btn removeFromSuperview];
}
```

You seem to assume that it will only process buttons - but you're wrong. You're just asking the compiler to trust you that everything in the `subviews` array is a `UIButton` instance. So what you are doing is iterating over all `subviews`, no matter what they are, and removing them.

To remove only buttons:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I indeed assumed wrongly. Thanks for putting me straight :-)